# Getting a browser process ID and then using it in the program in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, pid

I am trying to create a simple word highlighter for browsers (Chrome and Firefox) and I would like my program to use the process name (`chrome.exe` or `firefox.exe`) and then get their process ID.

I've found code that lets me get the process ID, but it requires a user to type the process name manually:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName);

int main()
{
   std::wstring processName;

   std::wcout << "Enter the process name: ";
   std::getline(std::wcin, processName);

   DWORD processID = FindProcessId(processName);

   if (processID == 0)
      std::wcout << "Could not find " << processName.c_str() << std::endl;
   else
      std::wcout << "Process ID is " << processID << std::endl;

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName)
{
   PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
   processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

   HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
   if (processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      return 0;

   Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);
   if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
   {
      CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
      return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
   }

   while (Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo))
   {
      if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
      {
          CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
          return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
      }
   }

   CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
   return 0;
}
```

Now, is there a way to manipulate this code for it to get the process ID automatically by checking whether the user is running `firefox.exe` or `chrome.exe`?

And after getting the process ID, how do I make my program understand that it needs to focus on said ID?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this approach is the wrong(tm) one to achieve what you want without a *lot* of pain. Have you considered writing a browser plugin/extension instead?

Comment: I mean, I taught myself only C++ so far, can I write a plugin with that?

Comment: [Google Chrome - Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Extensions), [Mozilla - Extension Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Add-on_(Mozilla)#Extension_technologies);
C++ with WinAPI ist just not the right tool for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Good luck doing anything with 'the' Chrome process ID.  There are at least a dozen instances of chrome.exe running on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, is there a way to manipulate this code for it to get the process ID automatically by checking whether the user is running firefox.exe or chrome.exe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName);

int main()
{
   std::wstring fifi = L"firefox.exe";
   std::wstring gogo = L"chrome.exe";
   auto fifi_proc_id = FindProcessId(fifi);
   auto gogo_proc_id = FindProcessId(gogo);

   if(fifi_proc_id && gogo_proc_id) {
       // both runnin O.O what now?
   }
   else if(fifi_proc_id) {
       // firefox running ... do stuff
   }
   else if(gogo_proc_id) {
       // chrome running ... do stuff
   }
   else {
       // none of both :(
   }
}
```

> And after getting the process ID, how do I make my program understand that it needs to focus on said ID?

I am sorry, but I don't know what you mean by "make my program understand that it needs to focus on said ID".

Comment: Oh, nevermind that question, I already see it's answer in your code. I forgot that I can use if functions to make my program do stuff when the certain process is running.